# How do I say "quirky" in German without sounding derogatory?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

I've looked up a few translations of the word "quirky" as they all seem to have a bit of a negative connotation attached to them (e.g., *skurril*, *verschroben*, *eigenartig*, and *sonderbar*).

How can I convey a more positive image in German?

Example sentence:

> I like her quirkiness.

Comment: Can you add some more context, please? help-info's "answer" is quite good, just a single sentence seems to less for an answer to distinguish meaning in context. verschroben and skuril can be used positivly - in proper context.

Comment: You should indeed add a definition of *quirky* in the sense you want it translated or expressed in German. Could a characterise a person that is quirky in the sense you mean?

Comment: @help-info.de: You should leave that as an answer (and support it), not as a comment.

Comment: The translations you found are no more derogatory in German than 'quirkiness' in English, really. Context here is everything and you gave none.

Answer (score 31):

All languages have words that are unique and hard to translate, because most other languages don't have a perfect matching translation for it. The German word *Gemütlichkeit* is one of them. You can translate is as *"cosiness, snugness, sociability, comfortability, warmth, friendliness, slowliness, homelikeliness, ..."* but all of those words matches only parts of the meaning of *Gemütlichkeit*. Other German words that are hard to translate are *fremdschämen, Schadenfreude, Nervensäge, Weltschmerz, Erklärungsnot, Mahlzeit!, Fernweh, Fiesling, Schönwetterfreund* and some of them even are used a foreign words in English: *doppelganger* (from German *Doppelgänger* literally: double walker), *kindergarten* (*Kindergarten* = children's garden) and many others.

The adjective *quirky* is one of the English words that are hard to translate into German. Others are *mind, awkward, doggy bag, no-brainer, serendipity, bromance.*

All you can do with such words is to step away from the word-to-word translation level and enter the "meaning level". Some call it *free translation*. You have to analyze, what is the meaning and intention of the speaker or writer, and then you have to re-think this meaning in the other language and express this meaning and intention in the other language. If you have to express ideas, that are easy to express with one of the words discussed here in one language, you maybe have to build complete new sentences in the other language.

This is what makes translation so hard. Every language has a set of words, and this set limits the way of thinking. Other languages have different sets with different meanings. So, speakers of other languages have other limitation of how they think. (And multilingual people have less limits of thinking, because they have more possibilities to think.)

If you grow up in an environment, where being *gemütlich* (adjective) and *Gemütlichkeit* (noun) are part of your everyday life, and then you want to say: *"Simon ist ein sehr gemütlicher Mensch"* or *"Dieses Café strahlt eine angenehme Gemütlichkeit aus."* or *"Ich trinke erst mal ganz gemütlich ein Bier."* in an other language than German, then you will get into trouble, because the idea that is connected with *Gemütlichkeit* is spread over many different words in other languages, and you have to find not only the best matching word for the actual context, but you also sometimes must provide the right context, that already is built into the original word.

The concept of quirkiness does not exist in German. (It exists in variations, but not in exactly the same way as in English.) Every German translation that is sufficiently close to the original meaning has a negative connotation. To be quirky means to be out of the norm, and being out of the norm is negatively connoted in most situations.

I don't really know the English word *quirky,* so I have no idea how positive or negative connoted it is, but the phrase *"I like her ..."* (in German: *"Ich mag ihr(e(n)) ..."*) already provides a very positive context.

So, although all nouns in this list are negative connoted in other contexts, the whole sentence still is positive:

> Ich mag ihre Verschrobenheit.
>   Ich mag ihre Schrulligkeit.
>   Ich mag ihre Ticks.
>   Ich mag ihre Marotten.
>   Ich mag ihre exzentrische Art.

- **Verschrobenheit** - eccentricity, crankiness
- **Schrulligkeit** - crankiness
- **Ticks** (plural of *Tick*) - quirks, spleens, tics, fads
- **Marotten** (plural of *Marotte*) - foibles, whims, fads, quirks
- **exzentrische Art** - eccentric nature, cranky nature, bizarre nature (also *manner* instead of *nature*)

Comment: I'd say 'quirky' combines a degree of eccentricity with some amount of cuteness or an affable nature.

Comment: I think you could drop the first and fourth paragraph to make the answer more concise.

Comment: Re "... and many others": My favorite quip is that the German words which made it into English show the contributions of German culture: *kindergarten*, *gesundheit*, and *blitzkrieg*.

Comment: Better leave out the part about language limiting thinking. Thought is not restricted by language, only expression of thought is. It's not like we could not appreciate a person's quirkiness, the direct way to express this is just a bit awkward (at least, if trying to translate from English instead of starting the process in German).

Comment: @Chieron - uh, no. It's been shown by research, many times over, that thought **is** limited by language. That's why bilingualism is so useful, far beyond just being able to speak to more people.

Comment: you can continue this discussion over at linguistics SE if you will, but you won't find a satisfying answer over there either, ultimately because neither term is well defined, whether in speech or thought.

Comment: Question: you say that your examples carry an overall positive connotation, but are they *inherently* positive (as quirky can be) as in *"I like her <trait which is usually negative but is positive in this context>", or does it come across more like *"I like her **in spite of** <negative trait>"*? If the latter, then perhaps it would be better to aim for a sentence like *"She is <negative trait> but in a good way"*

Comment: @JBentley it is *"I like her <trait which is usually negative but is positive in this context>".*

Comment: @Davor: “It’s been shown by research […] that thought is limited by language.” That’s a bit of an oversimplification of a very controversial topic, and almost certainly rather an overstatement. As @ vectory says, it’s a topic for linguistics.se more than here, but broadly my understanding is that very few linguists today would claim language *limits* thought; most would say it *affects* thought to an extent somewhere between “a small but significant amount” and “in a few small specific ways, but really nothing significant”.

Answer (score 17):

I would use

> Ich mag ihre Eigenheiten

it is relatively neutral in meaning so it doesn't have any negative connotation.
But of course it could be too neutral for "quirky".

Answer (score 15):

Of course, Hubert Schölnast is right about the problems of translation in general, and he also suggests a few good attempts at translating *quirky*.

The first word that came to my mind though was *ausgeflippt*.

> Ich mag ihre Ausgeflipptheit. Ich mag ihre ausgeflippte Art.

Used as a verb it can mean that someone lost their temper, but as an adjective it could also mean that a person is a bit out of the norm, unpredictable in a creative way, very active or of an agile mind, maybe a little hyped up. It's colloquial than what Hubert suggested.

Comment: *Ausgephilippt* wäre auch noch eine Variante.

Comment: @christiangeiselmann Ich fürchte, mit dem Vorschlag waren meine Eltern ein paar Jahrzehnte schneller als du.

Comment: Du wirst ihre Erfindergabe wohl tatkräftig unterstützt haben.

Comment: I don't think this really fits. In my opinion "ausgeflippt" describes a rather extrovert person, while a "quirky" one can also be introvert

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath As Hubert Schölnast points out in his answer, there’s not one translation that fits all the meanings.

Comment: I think "verspielt" instead of "ausgeflippt" could also fit.

Answer (score 9):

Merriam-Webster's [entry for quirky](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quirky) describes it as "unusual in especially an interesting or appealing way".

So one could simply say:

> Ich mag ihre ungewöhnliche Art.

An even better fit, because it usually has a positive connotation even in German (I think Volker Landgraf has a point with Germans disrespecting deviations from the norm, except perhaps in Berlin) would be:

> Ich mag ihre originelle Art.

Answer (score 6):

In a humorous context I would use `ulkig`.

> Ich mag ihre ulkige Art.

Some examples from [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulkig):

> Seine Kleidungsstücke passten farblich überhaupt nicht zusammen, das sah ulkig aus.
>
> Renate ist schon eine ulkige Nudel, die gratuliert keinem zum Geburtstag.

and from [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ulkig):

> mit der Pappnase sah er wirklich ulkig aus
>
> er ist ein ulkiger Mensch, Vogel

Answer (score 5):

As a supplement of Hubert's answer, it is a social phenomenon in German(y) that beeing too different from others is generally regarded negatively, therefore you will hardly find any word for "quirk" that has a positve or neutral connotation *unless combined with something like "I like..."*.
This is different from e.g. England, where it seems to be perfectly socially accepted that virtually everyone has a spleen or two.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted -- it rings true to my ears.

Comment: Everyone has a spleen (*Milz*), only psychopaths should have more. (*spleen* meaning *eccentricity* is old-fashioned, and othwise it tends to mean *Zorn* or *schlechte Laune*)

Comment: I think you are drawing German society too single-sided. There are sectors of society where some *Ausgeflipptheit*, some *Exzentrik*, some being *unkonventionell* or some *Extravaganz*, or even some *Unangepasstheit*, *Eigenwilligkeit* or *Verrücktheit* are well-received.

Comment: Dennis Rodman, a very quirky basketball player, has been called a "Paradisvogel". Your remark about bein different is undue, it would merely shift the question to a discussion about how different *different* really is. By the way *quirky* to me just means the IE 8 quirk-mode. That's not *ausgeflippt* nor *paradiesisch*. It's not *queer* either (and thus no *Querkopf* as would fit your answer). It's just *schräg*, ein *schräger Vogel* sozusagen. Das muss man nicht mögen, aber Worte dafür gibt es reichlich. *Quark reden* ist dann nurnoch negativ besetzt. Wie wärs mit *komisch, wirklich komisch*?

Comment: ... die Deutschen stehen ja auch in dem Ruf, keinen Humor zu kennen. Dann muss *komisch* doch, aus deutscher Sicht zumindest mer-kwürd-ig sein.

Comment: @vectory "komisch" hat ja auch eine doppelte Bedeutung: 1. "lustig", 2. "seltsam", deshalb vermeide ich auch dieses Wort in Situationen, in denen aus dem Kontext nicht sogleich hervorgeht, welche davon gemeint ist (abgesehen natürlich von Wortspiel-Witzen, bei denen wiederum die mehrdeutigkeit erwünscht ist).

Answer (score 1):

> Ich mag ihre unkonventionelle Art

... which puts an emphasis on defying convention without suggesting open rebellion. The extent of the defiance remains open to interpretation and in general the phrase suggests ingenuity, initiative, and thinking outside the box.

***Credits***

... go to @ChristianGeiselmann who noted the positive connotation of 'unkonventionell' in one of his comments.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the context (as many others have pointed out). If you don't need to keep the same sentence structure, you could say "Ich mag, dass sie nicht 08/15 ist, das macht sie interessant!"

Answer (score 0):

[DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) recommends "Ich mag ihre Eigenart." in the first try. If you are not satisfied with "Eigenart", it recommends "Macken" as the first alternative - which sounds better to my ears:

> Ich mag ihre Macken.

If you don't like "mag", the first alternative is

> Ich steh auf ihre Macken.

which sounds even better to me, but might express a little too much sympathy :) !

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "eigenwillig" for "quirky" and "Eigenwilligkeit" for "quirkiness".  Literally it means "with a mind of one's own".  It doesn't reach into the negative as "Sturköpfigkeit", "boneheadedness" does and is more about a refusal to be pinned down into a category rather than refusing to consider changing categories.